# What is the easiest way to export/produce/generate a report showing all workspaces, workspace members/roles?

Tags: powerbi

I have the Power BI administrator role.

I want to do an audit of all the workspaces, workspace members and their roles.

What is the easiest way to export/produce/generate a report showing all workspaces, workspace members/roles?